# How to transform this into a vector? - python

Tags: python, arrays, list, vector, format

I'm new to Python so I'm sorry in advance if my question is basic.

I've got a CSV table that I imported using this code (I found this code on a post from StackOverflow):

```py
import csv
with open('myCSV.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    so = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    so_data = []
    for row in so:
        so_data.append(row)
```

When I run `so_data[1:][1]`, I get this: `['1.25;10.25;1.25;5.25']`

I would rather like to get this: `[1.25,10.25,1.25,5.25]`, so I can use this vector in an input for a Python function I'm using.

How can I get this? Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

I tried other ways such as importing CSV with `myCSV=pd.read_csv(r'myCSV.csv')`, using `myCSV.iloc[[0]]` and `myCSV.iloc[0].values` and `myCSV.to_numpy()[0]` but I dont get the vector format I need.

EDIT
My data looks like that in the csv file:

```
a;b;c;d    
1.25;10.25;1.25;5.25    
11.25;2.25;1.25;5.25    
1.25;1.25;10.25;7.25
```

(NB: I tried to save the data in all the CSV formats allowed by Excel but I still could not get the vector format I need.)

Comment: how the data look like in your csv , provide some sample data

Comment: Thanks for your response @eshirvana, I edited my post with an image of the csv file. Is that what you asked?

Comment: remove the screenshot and paste raw data as text ( open it with a text editor) , excel processes the data

Comment: If the data appears correctly when opening it in Excel, there is a high probability that Excel is using the semicolon ";" as the delimiter instead of the comma ","

Comment: Thanks @hans_ob1! That was the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading a file using `csv.reader`, the rows are treated as list of strings by default (See the oficial documentation [here][1]).
You can try something like:

```
with open('../examples/data-1686519722934.csv','r') as csvfile:
so = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
so_data = []
for row in so:
    row_converted = [float(x) for x in ''.join(row).split(';')]
    so_data.append(my_list_conv)
```

This will iterate over the rows in our reader object (`so`) and convert each list of values into a string (`''.join(row)`), followed by splitting on the `;`. This generates a list of strings that are then converted into floats using `float(x)`.

It seems your delimiter is not ',', but ';'. You should fix that first.

Another solution is to just use pandas to open the csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv = pd.read_csv(, delimiter=';')
first_row = my_csv.values[0]
print(first_row)
Out: array([1.25, 10.25, 1.25, 5.25])
```

[1]: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#:~:text=csv.reader,transformed%20into%20floats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#:%7E:text=csv.reader,transformed%20into%20floats)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful comment! That worked with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

so your file delimiter is `;` and not comma , so read the csv with proper delimiter and you will be good to go:

```
so = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
```

output:

```
>> print(so_data[1])
['11.25', '2.25', '1.25', '5.25']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I used pandas as proposed by @Marcos Santana, it worked. Your solution works as well!

Comment: @statuser even with pandas you still have to pass the right delimiter

Comment: Yes indeed! @eshirvana

Answer (score 0):

> When I run `so_data[1:][1]`, I get this: `['1.25;10.25;1.25;5.25']`

looks like your delimiter is a semicolon. try `delimiter=';'`.

even then each will still be a string.  you will have to do something like:

```py
for row in so:
    row = list(map(float, row))
    so_data.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment (and also for editing my post)! I used pandas as proposed by @Marcos Santana, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the *iterrows* function is what you're looking for, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/11732784). I would then access each element in the series of a given row, and insert them into a new list (vector).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I used pandas as proposed by @Marcos Santana, it worked.